# Email template not full-screen on mobile

Tags: email, templates

I'm practising email for an outbound portfolio and I cannot for the life of me see why this isn't stretching to full-screen on mobile. Probably something really simple but some help would be much appreciated.

https://dl.dropbox.com/s/c759cldrl4t5ams/Test_email.html?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're on about IOS. If so - try putting `<meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting" />` in your `<head></head>` tags at the top of the email.

Comment: OH wow - thanks for that. Knew I was missing something simple!